# How do I know from which facebook campaign my purchase order was generated in woocomerce?

Tags: facebook, woocommerce, facebook-ads-api, utm

I am working with a client doing facebook ads campaigns. The problem is that he wants to know which ads produces the orders that are generated in his woocommerce store. My first idea was to track the UTMs of my campaign and add it to the purchase orders. For that we develop a plugin.

The problem is that after implementing it we realized that not all the orders that Facebook attributes to the campaigns are generated as a result of a click on the ad, and because the plugin stored a cookie when the click on the ad was made to capture the purchase event on the website, these other additional sales that facebook attributes to the ads are not captured by my plugin.

Looking for information on facebook what they indicate is that some conversions can be attributed only by the fact of an impression event and not necessarily by a click on the ad, I imagine that must be the problem. At this point I would like to know if there is any way to track all the conversions that Facebook attributes in ad manager to be able to identify in my client's woocomerce which campaign and ad generates the purchase orders. What I am looking for is the following image attached with the complete columns.

The 3 columns in red are currently captured by my plugin and are the Source, Campaign and Ad UTMs.

[image]

But for example, the order of the list below has also been attributed by facebook as you can see in these 2 images. ($ 18.29 = S / 76), however UTMs are not tracked. Any strategy to achieve this would help me.

[image]

[image]

This is my plugin code:

```
if (!defined('UTM_TRACKER_VERSION_NUM')) {
    define('UTM_TRACKER_VERSION_NUM', '1.0.0');
}


function woocamtrack_save_tracking_parameters()
{
    $cookies = array();
    if (!empty($_COOKIE['_woocamtrack_values'])) {
        $cookies = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE['_woocamtrack_values']), true);
    }
    $change = false;
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if (substr($key, 0, 4) == "utm_") {
            $cookies[$key] = $value;
            $change = true;
        }
    }
    if ($change) {
        setcookie('_woocamtrack_values', base64_encode(json_encode($cookies)), time() + 3600*24*7, "", "", true, true);
    }
}

add_action('parse_request', 'woocamtrack_save_tracking_parameters', 9);


function woocamtrack_add_columns($columns)
{
    $columns['utm_source'] = "Origen";
    $columns['utm_campaign'] = "Campaña";
    $columns['utm_content'] = "Anuncio";

    return $columns;
}


function woocamtrack_custom_column($column)
{
    if (!in_array($column, ['utm_source', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_content'])) {
        return;
    }

    global $post;
    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID);

    echo isset($data[$column]) ? $data[$column][0] : '';
}

// function woocamtrack_tracker_script()
// {
//   wp_enqueue_script('woocamtrack-tracker-js', plugins_url('/js/tracker.js', __FILE__), null, UTM_TRACKER_VERSION_NUM, true);
// }

function woocamtrack_save_order_cookies($orderId, $order = null)
{
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['_woocamtrack_values'])) {
        return;
    }

    $value = base64_decode($_COOKIE['_woocamtrack_values']);
    $values = json_decode($value, true);

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        update_post_meta($orderId, $key, $value);
    }
}


add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'woocamtrack_add_columns', 21);
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'woocamtrack_custom_column', 21);

// add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocamtrack_tracker_script');
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'woocamtrack_save_order_cookies');



// Export

function woocamtrack_custom_formatter($labels)
{
    $labels['order']->__set('utm_source', "Origen");
    $labels['order']->__set('utm_campaign', "Campaña");
    $labels['order']->__set('utm_content', "Anuncio");
}

function woocamtrack_custom_header($headers)
{
    $headers[] = "Origen";
    $headers[] = "Campaña";
    $headers[] = "Anuncio";
    return $headers;
}

add_action('woe_make_header_custom_formatter', 'woocamtrack_custom_formatter');
add_filter('woe_xls_header_filter', 'woocamtrack_custom_header');
```